# sort in bash problem with multiple columns

Tags: bash, sorting

I need to sort a file called lokdata

```
 (1) (260, 02) 0x2c435 0x2c43501 Thu Sep 27 09:43:21 2018
 (1) (60, 02) 0x2c435 0x2c43503 Thu Sep 27 09:46:14 2018
 (1) (260, 02) 0x2c435 0x2c43503 Thu Sep 27 09:46:44 2018
 (1) (260, 03) 0x4461e 0x4461e1f Thu Sep 27 10:31:05 2018
```

I need to sort that the most recent date is on top so I can use head.
My failed attempt example

```
    sort -k10,10r -r -k7,7M -k 8,8 -k9,9r lokdata


 (1) (260, 02) 0x2c435 0x2c43501 Thu Sep 27 09:43:21 2018
 (1) (260, 02) 0x2c435 0x2c43503 Thu Mar 01 09:46:14 2018
 (1) (260, 02) 0x2c435 0x2c43503 Thu Mar 03 09:46:44 2018
 (1) (260, 02) 0x2c435 0x2c43501 Thu Mar 29 09:43:21 2018
 (1) (260, 03) 0x4461e 0x4461e1f Thu Sep 27 10:31:05 2026
```

Comment: How does it fail? What output do you expect?

Comment: I just tried your `sort` and the one from kvantour's answer bellow, I get the same results!  So please explain what the problem is more precisely.

Comment: @Nic3500 there will be differences on bigger data samples. The extract is very unlucky as the only differences here are the times.

Comment: output (1) (260, 03) 0x4461e 0x4461e1f Thu Sep 27 10:31:05 2018

Comment: I need the newest line, those dates are similar but its not always like this

Comment: (1) (260, 02) 0x2c435 0x2c43501 Thu Sep 27 09:43:21 2018
    (1) (260, 02) 0x2c435 0x2c43503 Thu Mar 01 09:46:14 2018
    (1) (260, 02) 0x2c435 0x2c43503 Thu Mar 03 09:46:44 2018
    (1) (260, 02) 0x2c435 0x2c43501 Thu Mar 29 09:43:21 2018
    (1) (260, 03) 0x4461e 0x4461e1f Thu Sep 27 10:31:05 2026
After  kvantour filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I had to search a bit, but here is the solution:

```
sort -k10nr,10 -k7Mr,7 -k8nr,8 -k9r,9
```

which outputs

```
 (1) (260, 03) 0x4461e 0x4461e1f Thu Sep 27 10:31:05 2026
 (1) (260, 02) 0x2c435 0x2c43501 Thu Sep 27 09:43:21 2018
 (1) (260, 02) 0x2c435 0x2c43501 Thu Mar 29 09:43:21 2018
 (1) (260, 02) 0x2c435 0x2c43503 Thu Mar 03 09:46:44 2018
 (1) (260, 02) 0x2c435 0x2c43503 Thu Mar 01 09:46:14 2018
```

**How does it work?**

1. `-k10nr,10`: do a reverse numeric sort on the 10th field which represents the year
2. `-k7Mr,7`: the second sort is a month-sort which uses the standard 3 character month notation for sorting, again reversed.
3. `k8nr,8`: the third sort is on the day of the month which is again numeric reversed.
4. `-k9r,9`: finally sort the 9 fields as a string which represents the time, remarkably reversed.

**Why is it so complicated?** From the moment you define one modifier, in the key-specification, the global flags `-r` or `-n` or whatever no longer apply. So it is not possible to mix global flags with local key modifiers.

Comment: Sep 2 is represented as Sep 02

Comment: I added code to title thread as it appears I'm to stupid to comment with code. I need the most new date in first line and the output is not correct on more complcated example

Answer (score 0):

1. Add to each line number of seconds since epoch from the date it has
2. Sort by seconds since epoch
3. Remove the seconds since epoch

```
cat lokdata |
xargs -d'\n' -l1 -- sh -c 'echo "$(date --date="$(<<<"$1" cut -d " " -f7-)" +%s)" "$1"' -- | 
sort -r -n -k1 | 
cut -d ' ' -f2-
```

To save our CPUs from overheating, change `cat lokdata |` to `< lokdata`.

Life example on [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/JKTJJ1).